# LG G Flex Power button hangs-up when on calls

Tags: root-access, lg

LG G Flex Rooted no Roms. I have the power button hangs up on calls unchecked, but it hangs up when I am on a call. What do I need to do fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. In order to fix this turn off your phone. Hold volume up, volume down and power button until Hardware key control mode show up, press the volume down key and select Mode OFF. Press the power button to confirm, the phone will reboot and that should fix the problem.